# Android frame layout in xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout, android-framelayout

I have a frame layout in which I have a list view ,edit text and a button but now I want to put a button at the top right corner of the layout above the list view but I am facing problem. My xml is:[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent" >

      <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="86dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Send" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
        android:ems="10" />

  </RelativeLayout>

  <ListView
      android:id="@android:id/list"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="317dp" >

  </ListView>

        </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to describe the problem you are experiencing,

Comment: I want to add button at the top right corner in the layout but am unable to do this.

Comment: A screenshot of the result you're looking for would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well FrameLayouts are designed to usually only hold one child element. They are kind of like a wild card. So I would advise using it how you posted. Instead, make the relative layout the root layout.

Here is an example of how to make that work.

Pic:

[image]

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="NEW BUTTON!" />

  <ListView
   android:id="@+id/list"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="317dp" 
   android:layout_below="@+id/button2">
  </ListView>

  <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:text="Send" />

  <EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/list"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
    android:ems="10" />

</RelativeLayout>
```